# 件名で検索し、スプレッドシートに抽出したいが800件以上抽出できない

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-spreadsheet

Gmailから特定の単語を件名に含んだメールをスプレッドシートに抽出したいです。
（受信日時、件名、本文をプレーンテキストで）

ですが、799件までは抽出できるのですが、そこで止まってしまいます。
エラーメッセージは表示されません。
大変困っておりまして、ご回答頂けますと幸いです。

```
function test() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var max = 500

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var threads = GmailApp.search('subject:(hogehoge)', i*max+1, max);

        for(var i=0; i<threads.length; i++){
            var thread = threads[i];
            var mails = thread.getMessages();

            for(var j=0; j<mails.length; j++){
                var mail = mails[j];
                sheet.appendRow([mail.getDate(), mail.getSubject(), mail.getPlainBody()]);
            }
        }
        if (threads.length === 0) break;
    }
}
```

Comment: 古いですが、この辺の記事 [Google Apps Script メール情報をスプレッドシートに書き出す](https://dev.classmethod.jp/etc/google-apps-script-gmail-to-spreadsheet/), [Google Apps ScriptにおけるGmailの読み取り件数の制限とその対処法](https://tonari-it.com/gas-gmail-search-limit/), [Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) の最新の状況を考慮してどう対処しているかを追記すれば、有用な答えが得られやすいでしょう。